# Finding the distribution of the sample mean given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ independent R.Vs following $\operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent $\operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variables. Find the distribution of the
the sample mean $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$.

To answer this question, I used the Moment-generating function. However, I got stuck at one of the steps, and I don't know how to continue. Here is what I tried doing,

\begin{align}
E(e^\bar{X}) & = E(e^{\frac{t}{n}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}) \\[6pt]
& = E(e^{\frac{t}{n}x_1+\cdots+\frac{t}{n}x_n}) \\[6pt]
& = M_{x_1}\left(\frac{t}{n}\right) + \cdots + M_{x_n}\left(\frac{t}{n}\right) \\[6pt]
& = \left[e^{\mu(\frac{t}{n})+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(\frac{t}{n})^2}\right]^n \\[6pt]
& = \left[e^{\mu t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2}{n}t^2}\right]^n
\end{align}

But, now since I have the expression $e^{\mu t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2}{n}t^2}$ raised to the power of $n$, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: $\left(e^a\right)^b=e^{ab}$ so $[e^{\mu t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2}{n}t^2}]^n = e^{n\mu t+\frac{1}{2}{\sigma^2}t^2}$

Comment: Does that imply that $\bar{X}$ ~ $N(\mu n, \sigma^2)$?

Comment: No.  $\bar{X} \sim N( \mu, \sigma^2/n)$  and $[e^{\mu(\frac{t}{n})+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(\frac{t}{n})^2}]^n =e^{\mu t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2}n t^2}$ .  You have other errors such as addition instead of multiplication

Comment: I see, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\left[e^{\mu t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2}{n}t^2}\right]^n = e^{n\mu t + \frac 1 2 \sigma^2 t^2}
$$
It's a bit easier to read if you write it like this:
$$
\left[\exp\left( \mu t+ \frac 1 2 \cdot\frac{\sigma^2} n t^2 \right)\right]^n = \exp\left( n\mu t + \frac 1 2 \sigma^2 t^2 \right)
$$